# Getting "PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate, spring-webclient

I am consuming a third-party rest endpoint (B) from my application A using Spring boot Webclient. It is working as expected. The third-party REST endpoint is secured using SSL. I got a certificate from 3rd party service and placed it in the resources folder.

I use the following code to add the certificate

```
WebClient webclient = createWebClient();


public WebClient createWebClient() throws SSLException, FileNotFoundException{
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(ResourceUtils.getFile(somecertificate)).build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newConnection().secure(SslProvider.addHandlerConfigurator(sslProvider, sslHandler -> {
    SSLEngine engine = sslHandler.engine();
    engine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
    SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters();
    List<SNIMatcher> matchers = new LinkedList<>();

    SNIMatcher matcher = new SNIMatcher(0) {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(SNIServerName serverName) {
        return true;
    }
};

matchers.add(matcher);
params.setSNIMatchers(matchers);
engine.setSSLParameters(params);
}));

ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
return Weblcient.builder().clientConnector(connector).baseUrl(“someURL”)
.defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).build(); 
}
```

Now I am trying to mimic the third-party REST endpoint for some testing. Let’s call it C(Wrapper around third-party REST endpoint). When I try to access C from A, I am getting the following error

"PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

A -> C -> B (third-party REST endpoint)

A -> B is working properly
A -> C is not working. Getting certificate issues
C -> B is working. (C also sends the certificate when calling B)

**Do I need to make any changes in C to make it work? i.e. How to accept the certificate sent by A and pass it to B?**

If I comment on the SSL part from my code on A everything is working as expected. But I do not want to comment since this is just for my testing.

I cannot make any changes in B. I can make code changes only in C. I also tried adding the certificate to my local java carerts using keytool. But still, I am getting the same error.

Note:
I am already using WireMock for testing it locally. The third-party REST endpoint is not accessible from the local machine. WireMock mock response is static. I need a dynamic response. So I am writing a wrapper around the third-party REST endpoint and deploying the same in PCF. I've access to PCF from the local machine and PCF has access to the third-party REST endpoint.